# RegEx como separar por grupos cada ocorrencia

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Estou tentando adicionar atributos em uma marcação de tag `<a>` oriunda de um parse de `Markdown` (markdown => html).

Em meu documento `markdown` eu adiciono parenteses e a marcação que desejo logo após declarar os links, por exemplo:

```
[Cool Text](https://hiperlynck "title")(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")
```

O parser faz seu trabalho corretamente e me devolve apenas a substituição da marcação que ele reconhece:

```
<a href="https://hiperlynk" title="title">Cool Text</a>(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")
```

Deste ponto em diante tenho de encontrar o que adicionei entre parenteses ao final da marcação `markdown` e adicioná-los detro da abertura da tag `<a>`. Estou usando o seguinte `RegEx`: `/(<a.+<\/a>)\((.+=".+" ?)+\)/g`

O código abaixo é o que tenho por hora:

```js
let regex = /(<a.+<\/a>)\((.+=".+" ?)+\)/g
let str = '<a href="https://hiperlynk" title="title">Cool Text</a>(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")'.replace(regex, (match, $1, $2) => {
    if ( !$1 && !$2 ) {
        let url = match.match(/"(.*?)"/)[1]
        // checar se é link local ou para o mesmo hostname
        if ( url.includes(window.location.hostname) || url[0] == '/' || url[0] == '.' || url[0] == '#' ) {
            // caso seja link local, retorna
            return match
        }
        // aqui assume não ser um link local e adiciona atributos
        let allHrefContent = match.match(/^<a (.*?)>/)[1];
        if ( !allHrefContent.includes('target="') ) {
            allHrefContent += ' target="about:blank"'
        }
        allHrefContent += ' rel="noopener noreferrer"'
        return `<a ${allHrefContent}>${match.match(/>(.*?)</)[1]}</a>`
    } else {
        // aqui a segunda ocorrência é tudo aquilo que foi adicionado entre parenteses do `markdown` após o link
        if ( /^(rel=")/.test($2) ) {
            let rel = $2.replace(/rel="|"/g, '');
            if ( !rel.includes('noopener') ) {
                rel += ' noopener'
            }
            if ( !rel.includes('noreferrer') ) {
                rel += ' noreferrer'
            }
            return $1.replace('">', `" target="about:blank" rel="${rel}" ${$2}>`)
        } else {
            return $1.replace('">', `" target="about:blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" ${$2}>`)
        }
    }
})

document.body.innerHTML = str
console.log(str)
```

```css
.ext-link-icon {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='rgb(51, 103, 214)'%3E%3Cpath d='M19 19H5V5h7V3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2v7zM14 3v2h3.59l-9.83 9.83 1.41 1.41L19 6.41V10h2V3h-7z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") right/12px no-repeat;
  padding-right: 0.875em;
}
```

Funciona de boa com apenas um link mas, se tiver mais de um quebra e não estou conseguindo formular a lógica para agrupar as ocorrências.

Exemplo com mais de um link:

```js
let regex = /(<a.+<\/a>)\((.+=".+" ?)+\)/g
let str = '<a href="../">Voltar</a>(class="patinho-feio") qualquer coisa aqui <a href="https://hiperlynk" title="title">Cool Text</a>(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")'.replace(regex, (match, $1, $2) => {
    if ( !$1 && !$2 ) {
        let url = match.match(/"(.*?)"/)[1]
        // checar se é link local ou para o mesmo hostname
        if ( url.includes(window.location.hostname) || url[0] == '/' || url[0] == '.' || url[0] == '#' ) {
            // caso seja link local, retorna
            return match
        }
        // aqui assume não ser um link local e adiciona atributos
        let allHrefContent = match.match(/^<a (.*?)>/)[1];
        if ( !allHrefContent.includes('target="') ) {
            allHrefContent += ' target="about:blank"'
        }
        allHrefContent += ' rel="noopener noreferrer"'
        return `<a ${allHrefContent}>${match.match(/>(.*?)</)[1]}</a>`
    } else {
        // aqui a segunda ocorrência é tudo aquilo que foi adicionado entre parenteses do `markdown` após o link
        if ( /^(rel=")/.test($2) ) {
            let rel = $2.replace(/rel="|"/g, '');
            if ( !rel.includes('noopener') ) {
                rel += ' noopener'
            }
            if ( !rel.includes('noreferrer') ) {
                rel += ' noreferrer'
            }
            return $1.replace('">', `" target="about:blank" rel="${rel}" ${$2}>`)
        } else {
            return $1.replace('">', `" target="about:blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" ${$2}>`)
        }
    }
})

document.body.innerHTML = str
console.log(str)
```

```css
.ext-link-icon {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='rgb(51, 103, 214)'%3E%3Cpath d='M19 19H5V5h7V3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2v7zM14 3v2h3.59l-9.83 9.83 1.41 1.41L19 6.41V10h2V3h-7z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") right/12px no-repeat;
  padding-right: 0.875em;
}
```

---

Confesso que `RegEx` não é minha praia ... então a pergunta sucinta é: **como posso capturar dois ou mais grupos seguindo este parâmetro?**

```
<a>text</a>(class="foo") qualquer coisa aqui <a>text</a>(class="bar")
```

Para que possa chegar no resultado esperado:

```
<a class="foo">text</a> qualquer coisa aqui <a class="bar">text</a>
```

---

Desde de já grato por qualquer ajuda me leve a entender o problema.

Comment: Se usar DOM e usar nextSibling provavelmente vai pegar o texto a seguir dos elementos especificado e com removeChild poderá remove-los, e tendo o valor do #textnode vai poder fácilmente converter em atributo para o elemento anterior. Resumindo, se entendi sua dúvida regex parece totalmente dispensável para esse caso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não entendi muito bem sua sugestão. Estou manipulando uma string antes de acomodar ao DOM...pq colocaria no DOM para depois retirá-la? Desculpe se entendi errado.

Comment: Você quer converter os textos `(class="foo")` para o elementos precedentes, certo? E esses textos depois do atributo class adicionado ao elemento, ou entendi errado?

Comment: Quero pegar o que esta em colchetes `()` no caso `class="foo"`  e adicionar dentro da tag `<a>` antes de acomoda-los ao DOM ... quando lançar ao DOM já estaram com os atributos. Consigo chegar a este resultado com um link na `string` más, não com 2 ou mais

Comment: Bem, parece exatamente o que eu disse :) ... então poderia usar [`domparsed = DOMParser.parseFromString(sua string aqui, "text/html")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) para tratar seu texto antes de adicionar como DOM na página e então seleciona todos elementos A com `var links = domparsed.getElementsByTagName('a')` e então com um for vai vendo item por item do links e cada um deles você checa o [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling), com essa propriedade você pega o valor do texto `(class="nome da classe")`

Comment: Não faça parser de HTML com regex. As expressões regulares não são uma ferramenta suficientemente sofisticada para entender as construções empregadas pelo HTML. Veja [Analisando Html ao jeito Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: @AugustoVasques não tive tempo de "otimizar", mas a grosso modo deixei algo pronto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495414/3635 ... espero que eu tenha entendido a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da pergunta você tem isso gerado:

```
<a href="https://hiperlynk" title="title">Cool Text</a>(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")
```

Você quer pegar os atributos customizados que o seu "parser" inicialmente não faz, a segunda parte, que esta usando essa regex `/(<a.+<\/a>)\((.+=".+" ?)+\)/g` pode funcionar em um loop com `String.prototype.match()`, mas essa regex além de problemática (da forma que foi feita) exigiria que os valores pegos dentro do parênteses fossem tratados a parte, o que é muito trabalhoso.

Até aonde entendi tudo isso é uma string e não DOM ainda, então a tratativa pode ser feita com `new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, "text/html")` e para pegar os textos na sequencia dos elementos use o `Node.nextSibling` (que **diferente** do `Node.nextElementSibling` irá pegar textos e/ou elementos)

Um exemplo mais prático:

```js
let preParsedData = `
<a href="https://hiperlynk" title="title">Cool Text</a>(class="ext-link-icon" data-super="..." foo="bar")
foo bar
<a>text</a>(class="foo") qualquer coisa aqui <a>text</a>(class="bar")
foo bar
<a>invalido</a><br>
<a>invalido</a>`;

// Faz o parse da string
let docParsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(preParsedData, "text/html");

// Cria um template para gerar os atributos em elementos "falsos"
let template = docParsed.createElement('template');

// Pega todos elementos A
let anchors = docParsed.getElementsByTagName("a");

// Interage todos elementos ancora
for (let mainElement of anchors) {

    // Obtêm o próximo node (que pode ser texto, html ou NULL)
    let node = mainElement.nextSibling;

    // Checa se não é nulo e se é texto, também checa se começa com (    
    if (!node || !node.nodeValue || node.nodeValue[0] !== '(') {
        continue;
    }

    // Obtêm a posição do )
    let text = node.nodeValue, lastChar = text.indexOf(')');

    // Se não encontrar o ) significa que não é uma sintaxe válida
    if (lastChar === -1) {
        continue;
    }

    // Remove do texto a parte que representava os atributos
    node.nodeValue = text.substr(lastChar + 1);

    // pega os atributos para aplicar diretamente a um elemento "temporário"
    let strAttrs = text.substr(1, lastChar - 1);

    template.innerHTML = `<div ${strAttrs}></div>`;

    // Pega todos atributos do elemento temporário
    let attrs = template.content.firstChild.attributes;
    
    for (let attribute of attrs) {

        // Remove o atributo do elemento temporário
        let deatch = attrs.removeNamedItem(attribute.name);

        // Aplica o atributo removido para o elemento A
        mainElement.attributes.setNamedItem(deatch);
    }
}


// Obtêm o resultado em string (se for necessário)
let results = docParsed.body.innerHTML;

console.log(results);
```

Isso é apenas uma sugestão, não testei questões de micro-otimização, o objetivo é mais o entendimento. Fora os métodos já citados no começo da resposta também foi usado:

- `NamedNodeMap.removeNamedItem()` para remover (desanexar) um atributo
- `NamedNodeMap.setNamedItem()` para adicionar um atributo
- `Element.attributes` para obter o `NamedNodeMap` do elemento (lista de atributos)

E claro algumas operações simples com string.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, eu acredito que sua resposta atenda a questão. Segui seus comentários ontem e cheguei algo pouco diferente (atendendo as minhas necessidades) usando `DOMParser()`. Primeira vez que usei `DOMParser()`, me pareceu fácil, foi bom ter aprendido algo novo. Caso queira dar uma olhada no que fiz com as sugestões que me passou coloquei em um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/cvmnea8z/). Mais uma vez grato.

Comment: **"Até aonde entendi tudo isso é uma string e não DOM ainda"**. Sim vc entendeu certo

Comment: Não está ruim @LauroMoraes, mas isso de usar spread para coisas simples e ainda teve que usar regex tornou um pouco mais complicado do que poderia ser. De qualquer forma esta bom ainda sim, que bom que pude lhe ajudar.